# Getting rid of initial space in ggplot graph R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that has the data for the US GDP, trend, cycle, and drift (data at the end) from 1970 to 2022.

This is my code for making the graph

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% gather(key = "Serie", value = "Value", -date)

df1 %>%
 filter(Serie %in% c("Data", "Trend")) %>%
 ggplot() +
 aes(x = as.yearqtr(date), y = exp(Value), colour = Serie) +
 geom_line(size = 0.75) +
 scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", 
 direction = 1) +
 labs(x = "Quarter", y = "Billions of USD", 
      title = "UCM - Data and Trend", 
      subtitle = "Guess made with Hodrick and Prescott Filter (1600) and MLE.", 
      caption = "Data obtained from FRED St. Louis") +
 theme_light() +
 theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
       plot.title = element_text(size = 20L, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5), 
       plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 15L, hjust = 0.5),
       axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
 scale_x_yearqtr(format = '%Y Q%q', n = 85)
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Note that at the very start and at the end the graph has a gap. How I can get rid of these spaces? I have tried the `limits` but doesn't work.

## Data

---

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(date = structure(c(90, 181, 273, 365, 455, 546, 
638, 730, 821, 912, 1004, 1096, 1186, 1277, 1369, 1461, 1551, 
1642, 1734, 1826, 1916, 2007, 2099, 2191, 2282, 2373, 2465, 2557, 
2647, 2738, 2830, 2922, 3012, 3103, 3195, 3287, 3377, 3468, 3560, 
3652, 3743, 3834, 3926, 4018, 4108, 4199, 4291, 4383, 4473, 4564, 
4656, 4748, 4838, 4929, 5021, 5113, 5204, 5295, 5387, 5479, 5569, 
5660, 5752, 5844, 5934, 6025, 6117, 6209, 6299, 6390, 6482, 6574, 
6665, 6756, 6848, 6940, 7030, 7121, 7213, 7305, 7395, 7486, 7578, 
7670, 7760, 7851, 7943, 8035, 8126, 8217, 8309, 8401, 8491, 8582, 
8674, 8766, 8856, 8947, 9039, 9131, 9221, 9312, 9404, 9496, 9587, 
9678, 9770, 9862, 9952, 10043, 10135, 10227, 10317, 10408, 10500, 
10592, 10682, 10773, 10865, 10957, 11048, 11139, 11231, 11323, 
11413, 11504, 11596, 11688, 11778, 11869, 11961, 12053, 12143, 
12234, 12326, 12418, 12509, 12600, 12692, 12784, 12874, 12965, 
13057, 13149, 13239, 13330, 13422, 13514, 13604, 13695, 13787, 
13879, 13970, 14061, 14153, 14245, 14335, 14426, 14518, 14610, 
14700, 14791, 14883, 14975, 15065, 15156, 15248, 15340, 15431, 
15522, 15614, 15706, 15796, 15887, 15979, 16071, 16161, 16252, 
16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 
17167, 17257, 17348, 17440, 17532, 17622, 17713, 17805, 17897, 
17987, 18078, 18170, 18262, 18353, 18444, 18536, 18628, 18718, 
18809, 18901, 18993, 19083), class = "Date"), Data = c(8.50649011732295, 
8.51566342191531, 8.50488920689207, 8.53168684907831, 8.53708346193046, 
8.5452794536921, 8.54763451674106, 8.56585706189667, 8.58830102479373, 
8.59770052959384, 8.61430647192973, 8.63875326286171, 8.64958105546111, 
8.64430819296019, 8.65375558591012, 8.64512068649636, 8.64749469857194, 
8.63799832260494, 8.63410936256524, 8.62186180776693, 8.62898176278495, 
8.64595344523797, 8.65932883606886, 8.68156731896942, 8.688877539844, 
8.69434959842774, 8.70157196402326, 8.71331754974965, 8.73257211588503, 
8.75045482188932, 8.75047667936968, 8.75366322933669, 8.79157799576387, 
8.80158295014605, 8.81493484617877, 8.81673110481581, 8.81779973194363, 
8.82520098961846, 8.82769861828828, 8.83083887327767, 8.81001891259668, 
8.80882973463175, 8.82730722555059, 8.84671202334012, 8.83927379203043, 
8.8511779081522, 8.84022247507422, 8.82456509068482, 8.82911670152355, 
8.8252863824664, 8.82568576544118, 8.83877816054279, 8.86127922651456, 
8.88107268018358, 8.90172021984608, 8.92107932025916, 8.93820968084411, 
8.9478041427236, 8.95597920710337, 8.96562327621725, 8.97438940472548, 
8.98954518609214, 8.99695096890625, 9.00624291185687, 9.01073657384329, 
9.02026100100679, 9.02561649191299, 9.03303907257601, 9.04376971589713, 
9.05240796709892, 9.0694325833699, 9.07458582425837, 9.08763926239583, 
9.09348144669825, 9.10671845519018, 9.11683310594565, 9.12443678116481, 
9.13181824097308, 9.13378681180841, 9.14465548734833, 9.14827803589371, 
9.14894293911821, 9.1397972995484, 9.13510764444529, 9.14287458390361, 
9.14791524271861, 9.15139482098104, 9.16329530423984, 9.17408014425818, 
9.1839127175709, 9.1942875115087, 9.19595590987726, 9.20176016707163, 
9.20652038510788, 9.22002948059498, 9.22968583596561, 9.24314583983808, 
9.24897418216638, 9.26036425099686, 9.26390493009039, 9.26688354659529, 
9.27535421762916, 9.28212163229115, 9.28958343694377, 9.30612471207602, 
9.31505482898305, 9.32538526233189, 9.33182012191241, 9.34830330580107, 
9.36073351538304, 9.36928428872428, 9.37922843541018, 9.38844404599581, 
9.4008938698455, 9.41692656361223, 9.42632056761155, 9.43463589951092, 
9.44777941410945, 9.46407372784693, 9.46771157645587, 9.48575366479825, 
9.48675090866784, 9.4926769326032, 9.48942945521969, 9.49562412074752, 
9.49161259516663, 9.49438190068296, 9.50263006303116, 9.50876622279462, 
9.5127933899007, 9.51409909476756, 9.5192530223055, 9.52814713021653, 
9.54467869055579, 9.55615306468873, 9.56186588029973, 9.56962310268135, 
9.5789915536283, 9.5891599534648, 9.60020752873593, 9.60506177259115, 
9.6128872929818, 9.61855050904261, 9.63194703474014, 9.63439986140538, 
9.63590329256726, 9.64430501599974, 9.64723670300895, 9.65360075470575, 
9.65960575512094, 9.66568368704112, 9.66160106974973, 9.66730770931016, 
9.66202485053, 9.63995205744575, 9.62822635399101, 9.6265325389092, 
9.63014530491167, 9.64076830006785, 9.6457563737328, 9.65538689740683, 
9.66308860447767, 9.66827110369205, 9.66585903631402, 9.67261665957135, 
9.6722289127807, 9.68338325301368, 9.69152921286022, 9.69607745378211, 
9.69782475613588, 9.69892253403181, 9.70756299299795, 9.70895587468536, 
9.71684123744181, 9.72392777850684, 9.72042053795755, 9.73318007678534, 
9.74476235889015, 9.74924224323164, 9.75734248378674, 9.7631257427765, 
9.76635425225214, 9.76781552753494, 9.77369003744944, 9.7767093627625, 
9.78270252164766, 9.78765910542639, 9.79236731481258, 9.79794935442704, 
9.80511511881461, 9.81447517487933, 9.82207476506509, 9.83037929588491, 
9.835187244743, 9.83741617717757, 9.8433762833067, 9.8512742561291, 
9.85810585543745, 9.8627858632789, 9.84966432371949, 9.75604296154678, 
9.82880570805687, 9.8398967421788, 9.85511918689719, 9.87139350427254, 
9.87708674806638, 9.89375484300172, 9.8897900688667, 9.88834675699691
), Trend = c(8.50974196702144, 8.52767113605285, 8.53125264026178, 
8.54448128565638, 8.55191154133818, 8.56014959823967, 8.56602152616773, 
8.57815361764268, 8.59283955861335, 8.60225370121754, 8.61536700712543, 
8.63302921264033, 8.64420509992516, 8.64652059057234, 8.65651455369678, 
8.655823003664, 8.66090140102615, 8.65841622585962, 8.65863553315552, 
8.65315059532296, 8.6590173134099, 8.67097806698521, 8.68101538153598, 
8.69692941730547, 8.70387457707235, 8.7097539541366, 8.71669544313398, 
8.72649114874019, 8.74114869583002, 8.7552613135059, 8.7584514509239, 
8.76349005541521, 8.7900782242835, 8.7999418904508, 8.81208578863595, 
8.8171750449318, 8.82166086530655, 8.82979949300022, 8.83485587189964, 
8.84015125080098, 8.83074399353505, 8.83250852431178, 8.84576388768697, 
8.85980918715914, 8.85815833918256, 8.86776639767884, 8.86381910675826, 
8.85669227063477, 8.86088148350294, 8.85999116842397, 8.8613704888335, 
8.87003640355094, 8.88439119812018, 8.89765092787356, 8.91186205459243, 
8.92576559188848, 8.93877272085468, 8.94773339797248, 8.95597634439171, 
8.96508637172981, 8.97373685428518, 8.98609752487352, 8.99418626508, 
9.00337656595441, 9.00983194643639, 9.01907978570401, 9.02594921132687, 
9.03393483140566, 9.04377815362598, 9.05248637006321, 9.06601551730042, 
9.07298549552783, 9.08442886013407, 9.09184844049438, 9.10344180782936, 
9.11335450686812, 9.1218917657968, 9.13027392903382, 9.13551767415896, 
9.14565262513623, 9.15167098894513, 9.15588021212723, 9.15425356082808, 
9.15466979022914, 9.16177838169446, 9.16728282443814, 9.17185038119077, 
9.18112632076658, 9.18988344638184, 9.19822961201687, 9.20698190347585, 
9.21086357568399, 9.21697907168958, 9.22243475604215, 9.23282409909545, 
9.2411760805407, 9.25180708302863, 9.25825746169499, 9.26787923549107, 
9.27311194957736, 9.27794099928934, 9.28577033877708, 9.29263492978406, 
9.29989162180418, 9.31234269652776, 9.32069002068464, 9.32992647346508, 
9.33701383208848, 9.34982649258412, 9.36054487790293, 9.36920932825628, 
9.37870222095731, 9.3878228436053, 9.39882370829593, 9.41198338933749, 
9.42156405076708, 9.43058130782879, 9.44234384748844, 9.4560131258889, 
9.46265396305803, 9.47741836491734, 9.48262988506132, 9.49048090192195, 
9.49294428255933, 9.50045918818677, 9.50199757075654, 9.50706631324118, 
9.51505514160981, 9.52181441057684, 9.52732282592684, 9.5311646639116, 
9.53701884268595, 9.54491756722278, 9.5572149077238, 9.56687162597697, 
9.57338551740765, 9.58103472558913, 9.58959389899143, 9.59865380580876, 
9.60828842776284, 9.61447742770338, 9.62230075728434, 9.62886768003032, 
9.63979909705616, 9.64460618392447, 9.64875611863247, 9.65665460596152, 
9.66141198764657, 9.66801643625217, 9.67436360663958, 9.68071335841133, 
9.68121464037551, 9.68701283703007, 9.68643617932949, 9.6759386653474, 
9.67055076325113, 9.67030334190911, 9.6728438289587, 9.67935627490109, 
9.68282718483838, 9.68902122086051, 9.69426915773952, 9.69820457357718, 
9.69784380356809, 9.70256038819587, 9.70322950519654, 9.71040372070847, 
9.7160294696622, 9.7197510218555, 9.72190720000968, 9.72363391521432, 
9.72958706927153, 9.73150721854942, 9.73710181815848, 9.74233278237917, 
9.74161142025846, 9.75001341951025, 9.75793769509608, 9.7620504176182, 
9.768280968169, 9.77328674839354, 9.77688783643937, 9.77945220558667, 
9.78445498952156, 9.78784909643086, 9.79291789168927, 9.79743107587232, 
9.80182804411136, 9.80673742829073, 9.81258660007463, 9.81977029948085, 
9.82609038303404, 9.83291730284142, 9.8378522319842, 9.84132743606514, 
9.84686327510922, 9.85352042941959, 9.85965239608183, 9.86461789903595, 
9.85940068710715, 9.80766096216887, 9.84840006308388, 9.85521471024643, 
9.86501594785557, 9.87577318546758, 9.88087030093163, 9.89234741344108, 
9.89235089160019, 9.89362970728362), Drift = c(0.00876934805508319, 
0.00876934805508319, 0.00798484742347405, 0.00869859050513785, 
0.00853839731206357, 0.00850311511824874, 0.00821475249079805, 
0.00861661769346805, 0.00920145907516493, 0.00922077617224941, 
0.00955513700342693, 0.0102158833790021, 0.0102903535184169, 
0.00969980269555905, 0.0097206555805626, 0.00901216544272249, 
0.00875458571240548, 0.00804464966015016, 0.00756676821703914, 
0.00679446917286052, 0.00674116611655956, 0.00703292042975485, 
0.00719660808539901, 0.00766037981881077, 0.00762316166394834, 
0.00753425905293667, 0.00750460472681567, 0.00761723813866146, 
0.007957838883662, 0.00825124976503494, 0.00801319937346962, 
0.00787499235033105, 0.00873483898252524, 0.00878618848365896, 
0.00893755304018977, 0.00876547224912785, 0.00857547830475481, 
0.00855620788158865, 0.00840268710873629, 0.00826705017854489, 
0.00749880898441525, 0.00725046046959034, 0.00750973573214856, 
0.0077912073161313, 0.00738540089445745, 0.00748077083714327, 
0.00699103037457248, 0.00638656990899201, 0.00629254565579716, 
0.00598529194546937, 0.00578828239269008, 0.00591138307458882, 
0.00627269540162667, 0.006571829961563, 0.00689909133959954, 
0.00719937520381006, 0.0074485611988665, 0.00751349788993566, 
0.00754485344751241, 0.00761220008711173, 0.00765692146103135, 
0.00785973534100484, 0.00786961985164264, 0.00792668413259462, 
0.0078630455969932, 0.00792300356092757, 0.00787734078203101, 
0.00788203823808491, 0.00796720407103633, 0.0079994104977351, 
0.00823995594420812, 0.00818466589659156, 0.00832664853303999, 
0.00828709796431078, 0.00843136072876291, 0.00849603848033705, 
0.00849783933883616, 0.00849278273890902, 0.00835068080290902, 
0.00842875704306836, 0.00832323517723537, 0.00814305778969516, 
0.00771502101624174, 0.00739513122422071, 0.00738256889259803, 
0.00730020577229995, 0.0071803381103991, 0.00727228250442412, 
0.00733744301779382, 0.0073817174277368, 0.00744188341813989, 
0.00728557475683409, 0.00723419726144797, 0.0071560960226647, 
0.00729809198495467, 0.00734437931447687, 0.00748873744860098, 
0.00744312767220537, 0.00753882762892696, 0.00743752606425099, 
0.00732294070772676, 0.00734518601304404, 0.00732407419535899, 
0.00732111420996135, 0.00754646266574778, 0.00758164236826136, 
0.00765433252963914, 0.00762942780140526, 0.00785709986019043, 
0.0079827779785751, 0.00801271874984047, 0.0080777299792636, 
0.00812353396272928, 0.00824990316603277, 0.00846552913985265, 
0.00851450176982697, 0.00853658037463149, 0.00867824519222467, 
0.00889741564791976, 0.0087983254373657, 0.00906029947712904, 
0.0088913013052015, 0.00884562393500527, 0.00856539511356856, 
0.00851927163112782, 0.00821277017625373, 0.00807473172353029, 
0.00807096020493371, 0.00801337238453928, 0.00790339771102835, 
0.00772508631906169, 0.00764295044634527, 0.00765417920751516, 
0.00785801677994863, 0.00793698005267409, 0.00787450682163435, 
0.00786461635151994, 0.0078951067418345, 0.00794624000118674, 
0.00802035739277851, 0.00793996403336701, 0.0079348440114973, 
0.00787479522703109, 0.00800897381556222, 0.00786841887447634, 
0.00770518703648156, 0.00771367239973982, 0.00758389943457562, 
0.00754090432705852, 0.00748850286638722, 0.00743851504232101, 
0.00713399113304465, 0.00707535375563884, 0.00673945346690178, 
0.00598280252692694, 0.00548366283248783, 0.00523208545079661, 
0.0051139323312641, 0.00517532291971814, 0.00510050422350814, 
0.00514850706565043, 0.0051528717457295, 0.00509942893277605, 
0.00485974174315719, 0.00485345754900052, 0.00466977665523716, 
0.00477971462241536, 0.0048168532254526, 0.00476877245926692, 
0.00465408652423337, 0.00452558262901325, 0.0045882492983133, 
0.00447112657838432, 0.00452044418161494, 0.0045516342192225, 
0.00432016284912235, 0.00449934536900206, 0.00464969140885665, 
0.00462611977987794, 0.00469655042275076, 0.00471012487128456, 
0.00466144078860539, 0.00456938429039034, 0.00458840951887651, 
0.00453598241740785, 0.00455937166623815, 0.00455734414223994, 
0.00455030400824399, 0.00456606680690067, 0.00462239219332519, 
0.00473482776695703, 0.00480441690920973, 0.00489320022292598, 
0.00489503202858093, 0.00483270477068434, 0.00486357078897124, 
0.00494230509115902, 0.0049945285751318, 0.00499325441516768, 
0.00454503771466801, 0.00207426206290954, 0.00377156238059728, 
0.0039051470288373, 0.00416397228583706, 0.00445340196653358, 
0.00448165955730176, 0.00478874438316463, 0.00457868183922835, 
0.00443382505519691), Cycle = c(-0.00325184969848451, -0.00304821011536003, 
-0.0170639306483613, -0.00357600609748221, -0.0058063797099135, 
-0.00584853634713394, -0.00939855681483361, -0.00328064720108951, 
0.00441576016541809, 0.00428703508911508, 0.00787047292851177, 
0.0147789575570301, 0.0143883186099637, 0.00672153598437573, 
0.00638855857199665, -0.00173137781110458, -0.00433596894195314, 
-0.0115381847063179, -0.0156866524654494, -0.0226815120105664, 
-0.0213821331377544, -0.0164165203925884, -0.013239921799277, 
-0.00692230608397309, -0.00677294691345193, -0.00724633393380808, 
-0.00699756941778727, -0.00505911631172084, -0.000453018696197064, 
0.00326062311243042, -4.60882158022354e-05, -0.00183967305457833, 
0.00969325968563246, 0.00958541507579247, 0.0108659369173312, 
0.00756882427460523, 0.00425167761886633, 0.00362170374393831, 
0.00108327152558706, -0.00101189520283713, -0.0124310638220463, 
-0.0151683813814376, -0.00993841835576914, -0.00475300203043662, 
-0.0107080104807815, -0.00831653058720742, -0.0154279186989035, 
-0.0238562712342198, -0.0234031491052109, -0.0264665849753862, 
-0.0275020385622891, -0.0231971878875657, -0.0152944605479404, 
-0.0090519993211175, -0.00283707920581793, 0.00243104026254668, 
0.00642001308161849, 0.00698409419070601, 0.00693578412541209, 
0.00750217530734152, 0.00764001006014437, 0.0104553258412026, 
0.00975838213620307, 0.00992270759942469, 0.00801506891809259, 
0.00837465645554031, 0.00690084655171964, 0.0064092455145177, 
0.00733487937224452, 0.0072785816272641, 0.0107914657672971, 
0.00895249082167362, 0.0106400019209633, 0.00908250170728649, 
0.0107977567180561, 0.0110100936772891, 0.0101290595186123, 0.00920348441732464, 
0.00601249986669126, 0.00684762195473648, 0.0044785025141597, 
0.00103085118063087, -0.00636064949428542, -0.01129328846253, 
-0.0105734386901621, -0.0111017583168616, -0.0122253276254237, 
-0.0096465795358793, -0.00773718402587073, -0.00634205170698414, 
-0.00479232856259236, -0.00705484357189501, -0.00734511960383721, 
-0.00806514600815138, -0.00498297813049947, -0.00378266846201088, 
-0.00101564368533375, -0.00170583636982434, 6.11045553061662e-05, 
-0.0016642049377093, -0.00347279860224634, -0.00280788906866356, 
-0.00293361236794077, -0.00274092115666329, 0.00131123242962299, 
0.00180072201949702, 0.00288532770232963, 0.00222400781070784, 
0.00590283944341711, 0.00754725882766735, 0.00743057319782121, 
0.00791806742059833, 0.00803944075589956, 0.009517355085781, 
0.0123872443039629, 0.0121927433813196, 0.0115573819019449, 0.0130029989730096, 
0.0156440456349063, 0.0126682411176626, 0.0160619119670615, 0.0118659065295576, 
0.0101073290495417, 0.00451651077902351, 0.00335869791113736, 
-0.00211872238026044, -0.00428605930202169, -0.00399560333748735, 
-0.00464145055042911, -0.0061226679130583, -0.0086406270579112, 
-0.00931889677973553, -0.00835677961088925, -0.00420661702096381, 
-0.00251767496057065, -0.00336851116484884, -0.00325751095464707, 
-0.00247044443695397, -0.0013981954606409, -2.47557980734913e-05, 
-0.00138621352337938, -0.00135859829777877, -0.00226480259985147, 
0.000198914545007424, -0.0022015118879062, -0.00478906870919535, 
-0.00424911466566007, -0.00609875404123165, -0.00632354347280923, 
-0.00668891028011867, -0.00698310222161736, -0.0115713986750184, 
-0.011609016181709, -0.0163465173783713, -0.0278314134455738, 
-0.0339978000024902, -0.035451946700186, -0.0345207454000646, 
-0.0306198340689342, -0.0293522666763617, -0.0261064640594173, 
-0.0238693956121943, -0.0227986533738111, -0.0249768407323278, 
-0.0230153529743632, -0.0242251489902068, -0.0203537612241729, 
-0.0180369295534718, -0.0173582553256127, -0.0178662786837185, 
-0.0185669727747271, -0.0159661283544865, -0.016630329499702, 
-0.014416356377427, -0.0126926123390718, -0.0155682797316975, 
-0.0112394225190989, -0.00775658176568947, -0.0075132216741749, 
-0.00569590232265695, -0.00499338588116574, -0.0054056557050204, 
-0.00651995163130207, -0.00565743206917389, -0.0060781786823105, 
-0.00517802912561567, -0.00478334961748658, -0.00450652831376184, 
-0.00386577184724797, -0.00258977754108462, -0.000467296304379358, 
0.000752640486484645, 0.00219698041424463, 0.0020464622174565, 
0.000819442847272919, 0.00127496641458746, 0.00250534676582272, 
0.0031842174191392, 0.00289904555286799, -0.00494591526947828, 
-0.0464592807598696, -0.0138240407289327, -0.0104046165171005, 
-0.00515052010524493, 0.000188053801320167, 0.000653256666934247, 
0.00580951243294936, 0.00176555634356192, -0.000839408714882326
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -209L))
```

Comment: Try `scale_x_yearqtr(format = '%Y Q%q', n = 85, expand = c(0, 0))`. By default ggplot2 expand a continuous scale by 5% of the data range on both sides of the scale which adds some space.

Comment: This worked! Thanks!! But is there any way to have it like 1% at the start and 0% at the end?

Comment: Sure. `scale_x_yearqtr(format = '%Y Q%q', n = 85, expand = c(0, 0, .01, 0))` or using `ggplot2::expansion` you could do `scale_x_yearqtr(format = '%Y Q%q', n = 85, expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .01)))`